# Not able to render react component in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react application.

i have problem in routing of component

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**app.jsx**

Here i am routing 2 component. Login and Main component. In Main component there are many router which will use for dashboard.

**My Problem** : In `<Switch>` the 1st `<Route>` can render but it's not rendering from 2nd router if i hardcode in url

> http://localhost:3000/#/login == rendering
>
> http://localhost:3000/#/main = Not rendering

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './login';
import Main from './main';

import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        window.token = '';
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route to="/login" component={Login} exact />
                        <Route to="/main" component={Main} exact/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/animate.min.css";
import "./assets/sass/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css?v=1.2.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
import "./assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css";

import Login from './login';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <HashRouter>
        <Switch>

          {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return <Route to={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
          })}
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>;
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: What do you mean not rendering? what is happening?

Comment: what are inside the indexRoutes

Comment: @janaka inside indexRouter there are array of routers. It is not the problem.

Comment: If move Login component to 2nd then it'll not work but Main component will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
```

Instead of `to` use `path`

Answer (score 1):

`<Route path="/login" component={Login}  />
    <Route path="/main" component={Main} exact/>`

Use **Path** insted of **To**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use exact attribute in main Route as shown below.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    ...
                    <Route to="/main" component={Main} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code

First in your `app.jsx` file:

```
<Switch>
  <Route 
   to="/login"       // <== should be path="/login"
   component={Login} 
   exact
   />
  <Route 
   to="/main"        // <== should be path="/main" 
   component={Main} 
   exact             // <== remove exact prop for the nested routes to work
   /> 
</Switch>
```

Here `to` prop actually belongs to the `<Link/>` component provided by `react-router` not the `<Route />` component, It should be `path` prop.
If you want to render child routes within `<Route />` component then we never use `exact` prop on the Parent `<Route />` component.

Second in your `main.jsx` file:

```
  indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
    return (
     <Route 
       to={prop.path} // <== should be path={prop.path}
       component={prop.component} 
       key={key} />;
     );
  })
```

Again change `to` prop to `path` prop.